# Can I fry my frozen Maitake pieces with other fresh mushrooms?

Tags: frying, mushrooms

I was given a bag of frozen Maitake pieces and read online that they are best cooked without prior defrosting.

Can I throw into the skillet a handful of fresh shitake or oyster after awhile?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, why not? If you're really worried about it, just saute the frozen and the fresh separately and combine them after the fact.

Comment: that was essentially my question; must I fry separately to achieve the fried texture vs stewed/steamed results.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem. Flash-frozen veggies usually need to be sauteed longer as the freezing process adds some liquid. I'd just start with the frozen, and once they've in the pan throw in the fresh. You'll just need to cook off the excess liquid to get a proper caramelization. High heat and keep tossing.